# Replacing every word in a paragraph with html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want replace every word in a paragraph with some html tags, for example, consider this text :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

and the result after replacing the words with html tags, it should be like :

```
<span class="word">Lorem</span> <span class="word">ipsum/span> <span class="word">dolor</span> <span class="word">sit</span> <span class="word">amet</span>, <span class="word">consectetuer</span> <span class="word">adipiscing</span> <span class="word">elit</span>.
```

Need some guidance on how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Tried. What have you?

Comment: Your question shows no signs of own research or attempts.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm bad at javascript. @PeterHerdenborg

Comment: That's fine, but as per the site rules, you are supposed to show what research you have already done and what attempts you have already made when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you van do this:

```
<script>

    var x="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit".split(" ").map(function (word) {
        return '<span class="word">' +word +'</span>';
    }).join(" ");

    document.getElementById('htmlForm').innerHTML=x;


</script>

<p id="htmlForm"></p>
```

Comment: Do you have any way to exclude the comma after word , because I just want to get the word @suchit

Answer (score 1):

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit".split(" ").map(function (word) {
    return '<span class="word">' +word +'</span>';
}).join("");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so, how about the spaces between words? how to prevent it after adding the html tag?

Comment: @Thanh Son Nguyen add space in join(" ").

Answer (score 1):

```
       var text = yourtext.split(' ');

       for( var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i++ ) {
           text[i] = '<span class="word">' + text[i] + '</span>';
       }


  });
```

In text you will get words with span tags

See more at: http://www.grasmash.com/article/jquery-wrap-each-word-element-unique-span-tag#sthash.y0DkyzDW.dpuf

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Firstly, OP's text is not in an array, secondly, there is no inserting of html tags going on in your answer, just an unnecessary casting of each array element to a string, which it already is.

Comment: Removed -1 now. I think you posted the answer too soon, or I was too fast to judge.

Comment: Okay No Problem i tried but stack overflow editor not applied span tag.